# Monitor memory usage of AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am a bit confused in monitoring of EC2 with and without Cloudwatch agent. As far as I know, Cloudwatch agent does not get installed by default on EC2 linux but some basic system metrics like CPU usage can still be monitored and shown in Cloudwatch.

My questions

- If I need to monitor memory usage which is not being monitored by default in EC2 now, should I just setup Cloudwatch agent and memory usage can be published to CloudWatch metrics?
- What about I don't setup Cloudwatch agent but just enable detailed monitoring? Can memory usage be monitored by just enabling detailed monitoring without cloudwatch agent?

Answer (score 4):

> If I need to monitor memory usage which is not being monitored by
> default in EC2 now, should I just setup Cloudwatch agent and memory
> usage can be published to CloudWatch metrics?

Yes, this is the correct way to monitor OS level metrics on your EC2 instances.

> What about I don't setup Cloudwatch agent but just enable detailed
> monitoring? Can memory usage be monitored by just enabling detailed
> monitoring without cloudwatch agent?

Detailed monitoring just changes the monitoring interval from 5 minutes to 1 minute, it doesn't enable additional metrics. CloudWatch can't reach into the EC2 operating system to see things like memory usage, so you have to install the CloudWatch agent on the server to monitor memory usage.

Comment: Thanks Mark B. So if I can see memory metrics of a EC2 in Cloudwatch, is it pretty sure that that EC2 has either Cloudwatch agent or deprecated monitoring scripts being setup?